# Difference between queryParams and content-type: applciation/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: http, post, request, header, query-string

I have a simple yet very practical question. When we send a request using queryParams does `Content-Type` header `applciation/x-www-form-urlencoded` automatically set to that?

In other words when we send a POST request to any server just like

```
http://localhost:8080/api/setnewemail?email=newemail@google.com
```

Does it set the body of the request to the `applciation/x-www-form-urlencoded` or do I have to manually add this header and put the data `email=newemail@google.com` to the body and don't have to add the params to the url?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Headers migh or might not be added automatically depending on which client your are using (for example browsers automatically add `User-Agent` header and some other headers) and whether your request is passing through proxy or any other web infrastructure component that can modify your requests.

Typically if you use clients like `Postman` or `curl` or some tool-set that implements HTTP client features in programming language libraries, nothing is added implicitly. You have to add your header manually in order to make HTTP server know that the the form data is sent within your query string.